In my three.js and react project getting error 'TypeError: fetch failed'
I got this error. how can i resolve this?
Parse 
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I am running this command
npx gltfjsx public/models/663948135363845edb1aab87.glb -o src/components/Avatar.jsx -r public

I need to convert glb into jsx to show my glb model in react app
